# Binding AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding, absolutelayout

I am trying to layout some rectangles in an AbsoluteLayout using a ViewModel to set LayoutBounds:

```
    <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="outerLayout" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,10,10" >
        <RefreshView x:DataType="vm:MyViewModel" Command="{Binding ProjectEditor.LoadItemsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding ProjectEditor.IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                            SelectionMode="None">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Frame x:DataType="model:LayoutItem" 
                               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{Binding Rect, Mode=OneWay}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"                                              
                               BackgroundColor="LightSalmon" >
                            <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Test_Clicked" />
                            </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Frame>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </RefreshView>
    </AbsoluteLayout>
```

`outerLayout` is located in a Grid that has an X-axis in Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" and an Y-Axis in Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0".

Frame `theBorder` is layed out correctly but not the frames in the CollectionView:
They have the appropriate width but heights are too small and identical for all Frame objects.

For test purposes I defined a TapGestureRecognizer to check the Frame's properties in the debugger:

```
        Frame frm = sender as Frame;
        var x = frm.AnchorX;
        var y = frm.AnchorY;
        var h = frm.Height;
        var w = frm.Width;
        var bounds = AbsoluteLayout.GetLayoutBounds(frm);
```

`bounds` has the values I returned in `Rect` through the DataModel but `h` and `w` are too small.

What is wrong?

**Edit:**

I applied the changes suggested by **ToolmakerSteve**.

HeightRequest seems to work. However, AnchorX, AnchorY and WidthRequest have no effect. The Frame is always drawn to the end of the Parent View:

```
<Frame x:DataType="model:LayoutItem" 
         AnchorX="{Binding Rect.X}" AnchorY="{Binding Rect.Y}" 
         HeightRequest="{Binding Rect.Height}" WidthRequest="{Binding Rect.Width}"                                       
         BackgroundColor="LightSalmon" BorderColor="Black" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" >
```

**Edit:**

I removed the first `<Frame />` because it is confusing and not necessary to understand my intention.
What I want is to layout a pattern of rectangles whose coordinates are given by `ItemsSource`. Can anybody give me some hints how to proceed?

Perhaps the best approach is to implement a `CollectionView` custom renderer.

(My activity here is my hobby, not my job. I am still learning about Xamarin MVVM Patterns, so it will last some time until I can show you my solution here.)

Comment: Too much going on in this question now. You have two different frames. One inside the outer AbsoluteLayout. The other inside ItemTemplate. Please remove one of those, both from the code you are testing and the code you show here, and edit the code snippet to show exactly what you are trying now. What is needed for the outer frame is completely different from what is needed inside an item template. You could create a new question for the one you remove from this question. An answer will be less confusing this way. Both for you, and for anyone else in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` has no effect except on **direct chidren** of the AbsoluteLayout.
The two children here are the Frame and the RefreshView.
Cannot apply it to nested elements.

- Inside DataTemplate, bind that inner Frame's HeightRequest and WidthRequest.
- Also set CollectionView's `ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"`.

---

**Positioning items of a CollectionView**

You can't. The CollectionView controls their position.
By default, they are in a vertical list.

Similarly, the Width is the width of the CollectionView itself.

If child is appearing at end of area, instead of start, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options.

Specifically `VerticalOptions="Start"`. Set that on the collectionview itself.

---

**Use BindableLayout with AbsoluteLayout**

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75688708/xamarin-forms-layout-rectangles-where-x-y-width-height-are-given-by-data-bin) now exists.

See Jason's comment with link to BindableLayout.

You would use AbsoluteLayout as the Layout. Read there for more details.

---

**A c# approach**

If you need to independently control the positions of items, they can't be part of a CollectionView (or any similar group, such as ListView).

Could create the elements in c# code, and add them to the AbsoluteLayout:

```cs
// Loop over your data.
foreach (.. item in ...)
{
    var element = new BoxView(...);
    AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(element, ...);
    outerLayout.Children.Add(element);    
}
```

Look up docs for `BoxView` and `AbsoluteLayout SetLayoutBounds`, to see the parameters.

NOTE: I've used BoxView instead of Frame. Test with that first. Frame won't work well until it has some element inside of it. You could test with a Frame containing a BoxView.

Comment: I think, the C# approach is best, because it is rather simple and easy to understand. MVVM would be too complicated.